# How to split buttons text in two columns

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button and I want to separate the text and the numbers automatically.
ex. Text=Programming, Numbers=1354.25
then the result could fit the Button Width. The Text will be in the leftmost side and the numbers will be in rightmost side.

```
Result="Programming          1354.25".
Result="Program                54.25".
Result="C#                 514754.25".
```

I dont want to add spaces because the numbers of characters in text & numbers varies.

Comment: WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET?

Comment: how to implement this? Button.Text="Text" + numberofspaces + Numbers.    numberofspaces must be the number of blank characters between text & numbers. It's Winforms

Comment: @XXX if you want us to answer your questions, then start with answering our questions. Its WinForms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the results you mention are the desired results, you could compute the number of spaces required to make a string of a constant length, ie (this assumes `Text` and `Numbers` are both `string`s):

```
int count = Math.Max(0, 28 - (Text.Length + Numbers.Length));
string result = Text + new string(' ', count) + Numbers;
```

However if you're not using a fixed-size font, these will not align properly. The `i` character takes less horizontal space than the `W` character, for instance. In that case you would have to handle the `Paint` event of the button and draw either or both texts separately.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume you have `words` array of `KeyValuePair` items for your buttons data. And you have buttons with names `button1`, `button2` etc.

First step you need to do is find max width of text which should be drawn on buttons. Without spaces, just data. You should use [Graphics.MeasureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb(v=vs.110).aspx) methods for that. You can get `Graphics` instance from `OnPaint` handler argument.

After that you can calculate amount of spaces which should be added to other buttons to get approximately same width of drawn text.

```
protected override void OnPaint (PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    var words = new Dictionary<string, decimal> {
        { "Programming", 1345.25M },
        { "Program", 54.25M },
        { "C#", 342325.25M }
    }.ToArray();

    var g = e.Graphics;
    var font = button1.Font;
    var maxWidth = words.Max(x => g.MeasureString($"{x.Key}{x.Value}", font).Width);

    SetButtonText(g, maxWidth, button1, words[0]);
    SetButtonText(g, maxWidth, button2, words[1]);
    SetButtonText(g, maxWidth, button3, words[2]);
}

private void SetButtonText(Graphics g, 
   float maxWidth, Button button, KeyValuePair<string, decimal> data)
{
    var minSpacesCount = 5;
    var spaceWidth = g.MeasureString(" ", button.Font).Width;
    var initialTextWidth = g.MeasureString($"{data.Key}{data.Value}", button.Font).Width;
    var spacesToAdd = minSpacesCount + (int)((maxWidth - initialTextWidth) / spaceWidth);
    button.Text = $"{data.Key}{new String(' ', spacesToAdd)}{data.Value}";
}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that if you have different fonts on each button its also not a problem. Just when calculating maximum width you need to use font of each button instead of using first button's font.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = "Programming          1354.25";

var pieces = result.Split(' ');
Debug.Write(pieces[pieces.Length - 1]);
```

This code basically splits the result into an array of strings, and then outputs the last index in that array.